# React Native / Expo / Typescript: JSX element type 'Text' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts (2604)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Can anybody help me on my early journey using React Native and Expo?

JSX element type 'Text' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

**App.tsx**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FrontCard from './components/FrontCard';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FrontCard />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

**FrontCard.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Text, { View } from 'react-native'

const FrontCard: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>test</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default FrontCard;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "canumind"
}
```

I have tried a few different things mentioned in search results from:
https://www.google.com/search?q=JSX+element+type+does+not+have+any+construct+or+call+signatures.ts+(2604)&rlz=1C1PRFI_enGB834GB834&sxsrf=ALiCzsbu2XjELqIQ0dOLQwdnq3sAj_g7PA:1668253602337&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF8fL6yKj7AhUJZMAKHRf0CqIQpwV6BAgBEBo&biw=1120&bih=972&dpr=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text` is not a *default* export, it's a *named* export.

```
import Text, { View } from 'react-native'; // wrong

import { Text, View } from 'react-native'; // correct
```

I wasn't even able to find the default export in `react-native` package, it's not listed in the `react-native` docs as well.

If the `Text` component would be exported from the `react-native` package with

```
export default Text;
```

you would be able then to import it as you actually did. However since it's exported with a *named* export

```
export { Text };
```

it can't be imported with `default` keyword since it's not a `default` export.

More information about `react-native` components: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text